# Sendgrid/PHP/Heroku Not Working

Tags: heroku, directory, sendgrid

I added the basic version of SendGrid to Heroku so we could send user-feedback emails from our website.  The basic testing implementation I'm using is below:

```
<?php
/**** Takes posted content from 'contact.html' and sends us an email *****/

require 'sendgrid-php/SendGrid_loader.php';
$sendgrid = new SendGrid('username', 'pwd');

$mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
$mail->
  addTo('matthewpolega@gmail.com')->
  setFrom('matthewpolega@gmail.com')-> 
  setSubject('another')->
  setText('Hello World!')->
  setHtml('<strong>Hello World!</strong>');

$sendgrid->
    smtp->
    send($mail);

header( 'Location: contact.html' );

?>
```

It works fine in localhost testing.  However, it stalls when I test it online.  Has anybody experienced a problem like this?

Comment: Can you give some more details about the problem your experiencing?  If you put some `echo` statements around the important events in your code, what do you see? (require, instantiation, sending, etc).  Are you sure your credentials are correct?  Does the request ever actually time out?

Comment: I put all of the files in my heroku_upload folder.  The sendgrid directory is committed, but not the contents.  When I try to do an add like `git add sendgrid-php/*`, I get `fatal: Path 'sendgrid-php/MIT.LICENSE' is in submodule 'sendgrid-php'`.  I don't think I'm handling submodules correctly.  I put an `echo` in SendGrid_loader.php and tried to include it in my index page, but it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're having some issues with submodules on Heroku.  There are two ways you can fix this:

1) Figure out what you did wrong by reading the [heroku submodule docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules).  It's probably as simple as `git submodule add path/to/sendgrid`

2) Remove the `.git` directory in the SendGrid module and check it in to your repo:

```
$ cd ../path/to/sendgrid_lib
$ rm -rf .git/
$ cd ../root/project/dir
$ git add ../path/to/sendgrid_lib
$ git commit -m "Removed SendGrid submodule and added to repo"
```

Comment: Followed the doc procedure and it ended up working, although I thought that's what I was doing.  Clearly I wasn't, and now I'm getting email.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it figured out!