# Sending email using SendGrid in PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendgrid

If I have a herokuapp, say, test.herokuapp.com, and I want to send an email from it, what do I do? This is what I have so far

```
$sendgrid = new SendGrid(username,password);
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
$mail->addTo('myActualEmail@mail.com')->setFrom('contactus@test.herokuapp.com')->setFromName('Jake from Statefarm')->setSubject($email_subject)->setText($email_body);
$sendgrid->smtp->send($email);
```

Is that good? For some reason it's not sending

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sendgrid/PHP/Heroku Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926554/sendgrid-php-heroku-not-working)